# Possible asc/desc number dataTable with adding Text?

Tags: jquery, sorting, datatable

i want to ascending/descending column with number ending in x .

**MyCode :**

```
        {
            targets: [4],
            visible: true,
            searchable: true,
            render: function(data, type, row) {
                return '<div style="text-align: right;">' + data + 'x</div>';
            }
        },
```

But, When I use that, ascending & desc sequence looks like this:

```
   1x
1200x
 222x
  34x
4000x
 529x
```

I Want to display like this :

```
   1x     or   4000x
  34x          1200x
 222x           529x
 529x           222x
1200x            34x
4000x             1x
```

**Is this possible? any reference?**

Image Reference [My Data]:

[image]

I Grab data from Facebook, and i display it into dataTable.
This is the data that is on facebook, and i want display like this :

[image]

Comment: Where is the data array coming from? Correct me if I'm missing something.

Comment: I grab data from facebook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify your render function to only change the data when the type is "display".  Then it will use the actual value for filtering and sorting.  https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render#Types

http://jsfiddle.net/Lsro1yhw/

```
 "render": function(data, type, row) {
      if (type === 'display') {
        return '<div style="text-align: right;">' + data + 'x</div>';
      } else return data;
    }
```